# a regex to match a pattern between two specific strings

Tags: regex

let's say I've a text like the following:

> THINGS H X F N AB end STUFF H X4 O 9D I,8U JK(S) XD LMJIK END OTHER_STUFF ....... end

I want to write a regex to get a the words between STUFF and the next following END (or OTHER_STUFF, in case end is not found):

> H X4 O 9D I,8U JK(S) XD LMJIK

I tried following regex, but I couldn't make it stop after finding the first end, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4jyt1t/1):

```
(?:\G(?!^)|STUFF)\s+\K[a-z0-9(),]{1,16}(?=.*?end)
```

I would be happy to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make sure `[a-z0-9(),]{1,16}` does not match `end`:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|STUFF)\s+\K(?:(?!end)[a-z0-9(),]){1,16}(?=.*?end)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4jyt1t/2).

Here, the `(?:(?!end)[a-z0-9(),]){1,16}` part matches any lowercase letter, digit, `(`, `)` or `,`, one to 16 times, as many as possible, that does not start an `end` char sequence.

See more details about [tempered greedy token here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).